# How to get Ping Status of any HTTPS End Point in Java?

Tags: java

I need to check the https URL is available are not.

Below is the code

```
URL siteURL = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) siteURL
        .openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
if (code == 200) {
    result = "Green";
```

When I am executing the above code iam getting the following error,

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>     at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:285)
>     at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:191)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:954)

can any one please provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the SSL site is passing you a certificate that you dont have in your certificate store as a trusted path. Add it, or ignore the site, or use a custom socket factory to ignore the issue.